# What is created when "Iron-Out®" is mixed with household bleach?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I accidentally mixed bleach in a toilet bowl that had Iron-Out in it. The gas almost overwhelmed me, and left me gasping for breath for a good 15 minutes. What in the heck did I create with those two chemicals?

Comment: This is potentially quite serious. Some people can have severe idiosyncratic reactions to sulfur dioxide. Go to ER **right now**. If you start to have breathing difficulties again, call an ambulance.

Answer (score 5):

**Good that you left for fresh air.**

Assuming it is the same product I know, it calls [here](http://www.superironout.com/powders.php) for **caution**:

[image]

The below mentioned data safety sheet available (SDS) [here](http://www.summitbrands.com/SDS) mentions for the [very product](http://www.summitbrands.com/Data/Accounts/Files/1/IronOUT(powder)-English-GHS-Rev3-16-15.pdf) as **composition**

[image]

and recommends as **first aid** (same source):

[image]

Upon the action of bleach, you likely generated sulfur dioxide, gas with pungent smell. Refraining from a remote diagnosis, but if you accident happened in a less ventilated space and you inhaled a lot, consultation of a **physician** may be adequate as sulfur dioxide ($\ce{SO2}$) is harmful and maybe you equally inhaled vapours of bleach, too.  Likely, mixing "iron out" and bleach together yielded a considerable heat, too.